# HTML CSS: why is my footer invisible?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout with a navigation bar that spans all of the pages except the footer. I also have top and right advertising spaces.

I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401359/3255963 to make the navigation bar go down, but it doesn't go all the way to the footer and the footer is missing.

How can I display my footer at the bottom and get the navigation bar to do to the footer?

http://jsfiddle.net/pfYt5/

HTML
        
    
    
        
            Page Title

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="navbar">
        <a id="navbarTitle" href="./index.html">Name of website</a><br>
    </div>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="topAdvertising"> 
            [placeholder]
        </div>

        <div id="main_core">
            <div id="main_core_left">       
                <div id="warning">
                This is a work in progress
                </div>

                <div id= "app_title">Page Title</div>

                <div id="app_input">
                    afjdlajfdaslkfjsalkfjasl;fjas;ldjfals;djflasdjfasldjflsajdfljlksadf: <br>                   
                    <li>dfjsalfjdlskjfdljfl</li>
                    <li>dsfjlakfjdljsflkjlj</li>
                    <li>skdfjlsjfldjfldjflf</li>
                    <li>dfjdlksjfldjflkjlfkdj</li>
                    jsljaflkdsjfldskjfldksjflkdjflkdjfldkjfdkljfld.<br>
                    fdljasflkjdaslfkjdslakfjds <br>
                    djfklajfldasjflds<br>
                    dfaskljfdalsjfdsla<br>
                    afdjklajfdlkjafld<br>
                    afdlkjlsdfjlakdfjlas<br>
                    afsdjljsfdlkjadflkjasfldkjaflkdjsafldaffasjdklfja<br>
                </div>

                <div id="text">
                <a id="linkid" href="http://randomweblinkjflksjflkdsjflkdjfldkjfldkjfldkfjdlfjdljfdlfjdklfj">Link</a> <br>
                <blockquote cite="linkjflskjfkldsjaflkdsjaflkdjsaflkjdsaflkjdslfkjdslakfjdslafjdslkafjdlskjfd"></blockquote>A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text. A lot of text.A lot of text.A lot of text.</blockquote>              
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="main_core_right_advertising">
                    [placeholder]
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    ©2014 Copyright
</div>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* This is a comment, by the way */

body, html {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

wrap {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 17%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 12px;
}

    #navbarTitle {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: white;
        font-style: bold;
        text-align: left;
    }

#main {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%
}

    #topAdvertising {
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 30px;
    }

    #main_core {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
    }

        #main_core_left {
        float: left;
        width: 80%;
        }

            #warning {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: garamond, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                font-style: italic;
                margin: auto;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                width: 70%;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            #app_title {
                font-size: 1.5em;
                margin: 0;
                margin-bottom: 7px;
                padding: 4px;
                text-align: center;
                letter-spacing: 0.05em;
            }

            #app_results_title {
                margin: 0;
                margin-bottom: 7px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #app_input, #app_output {
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: auto;
                width: 70%;
                padding: 12px;
            }

            li {
                margin-left: 15px;
            }

            form {
                padding-top: 12px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #resultsTable {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            #resultsTable td, #resultsTable th {
            font-size:1em;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
            }

            #resultsTable th {
            font-size:1.1em;
            text-align:left;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-bottom:4px;
            background-color:black;
            color:#ffffff;
            }

            #resultsTable tr.alt td 
            {
            color:#000000;
            background-color:gray;
            }

            #startOver {
                margin: 20px;
                font-size: 16px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #authority {
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: justify;            
            }

        #main_core_right_advertising {
            float: right;
            width: 17%;
            background-color: aqua;
            }

    #footer {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 20px;
        color: red;
    }

    a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id recommend looking at a different 2 column layout to start. Bootstrap is always a good place to start. At least look to see how they did their layout. CSS is much more complicated than it looks.

When you use absolute it takes the item out of flow, meaning the elements around the absoluted item arn't going to take into account the items dimension. You did this with main-core so the footer thinks the place in flow is after top-advertising. You don't see it because if you want something to show over an absoluted item you need to position it relative and give it a z-index.

Another issue you have is with float. For the element containing the float calculate its height it need overflow needs to be set, be clearfixed or it needs to be a float itself.

Edit: fixed some of the issues

http://jsfiddle.net/pfYt5/10/

```
/* added clear fix */
/* removed absolute on main core */
```

Comment: Bootstrap says it's for mobile-first apps. Do you recommend it for traditional browser websites too? It does seem like it woould be easier to start from scratch.

Comment: Bootstrap is great for getting off the ground. Don't worry that its says mobile first. It means that it is designed to be responsive with an initial focus on mobile. They use media queries for styling larger browser windows. Layouts in css is difficult especially if you don't know your dimension. Bootstrap uses a grid system with good defaults to help get going quickly.

Comment: If you want start from scratch, that would be great. Start from a working example though. Look at a few ways people did it. Play with it a lot. Plan to spend more than a few hours learning how it works.

Comment: I kind of got into this mess by using the example in my original post. Problem is if I modify it without understanding it well, it doesn't really work out.

Comment: Yeah, a stepwise aproach works much better. You need to understand what each piece does or you start spinning your wheels.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is not invisible. I am too tired to bother working on this right now, but after some tinkering, I've got it to show up in red text (it's actually near the top of the page):

[image]

jsfiddle.net/pfYt5/6/

Comment: Before I played around with it, I opened up Dev tools in IE 11 (F12) and browsed through the source of the jsfiddle document and the footer had actually been rendered on the page, it just wasn't able to be seen. It is there, just not sure why you couldn't see it. I can't think properly - too tired. It's there, though.

Comment: #main_core is position absolute. That's why it's covering up the #footer.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara That does uncover it. How do I get it pushed down to after #wrap?

Comment: @CarbonandH20 You would first need to remove position: absolute from #main_core as absolute positioned elements do not take up space. Then, you either need to add some CSS clearfix code, or for a really dirty solution, add clear: both to #footer. See this question for clearfix info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Answer (score -2):

Try putting in the footer

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: Still don't see it after adding that.

Comment: ah. this magical line of CSS has been the solution to many a positioning problem.

Comment: It's not nearly that simple. Some CSS clear fixing would help, but there are also absolutely positioned elements that are causing the layout issues.